# Decrypting two ciphertexts using the same key

Tags: one-time-pad

I'm currently trying to solve an online challenge, where I'm given two ciphertexts, encrypted using a one-time pad and the same key for both messages. The task is to decrypt those messages.

What I'm trying to do is to xor a common English word ("the" in this case) and for that word step by step XOR with the result of c1 XOR c1.

So basically: bits("the") XOR c1 XOR c2

My problem is that all the results I get are not usable.
I know that "the" should be the right word to find something, as the instructor dropped that hint.

My code looks like this:

```
def text_to_bits(text, encoding='utf-8', errors='surrogatepass'):
    bits = bin(int.from_bytes(text.encode(encoding, errors), 'big'))[2:]
    return bits.zfill(8 * ((len(bits) + 7) // 8))


def text_from_bits(bits, encoding='utf-8', errors='surrogatepass'):
    n = int(bits, 2)
    try :
        return n.to_bytes((n.bit_length() + 7) // 8, 'big').decode(encoding, errors) or '\0'
    except:
        return "Not processable"



def xor(bit1, bit2):
    result = ''
    for idx, val in enumerate(bit1):
        result = result + ('0' if (bit1[idx] == bit2[idx]) else '1')
    return result


def crib_brute(bit_str, crib_word_bit):
    for i in range(50):
        xor_result = xor(crib_word_bit, bit_str[i: len(crib_word_bit) + i])
        print(str(i) + ": " + text_from_bits(xor_result))


c1 = "1010110010011110011111101110011001101100111010001111011101101011101000110010011000000101001110111010010111100100111101001010000011000001010001001001010000000010101001000011100100010011011011011011010111010011000101010111111110010011010111001001010101110001111101010000001011110100000000010010111001111010110000001101010010110101100010011111111011101101001011111001101111101111000100100001000111101111011011001011110011000100011111100001000101111000011101110101110010010100010111101111110011011011001101110111011101100110010100010001100011001010100110001000111100011011001000010101100001110011000000001110001011101111010100101110101000100100010111011000001111001110000011111111111110010111111000011011001010010011100011100001011001101110110001011101011101111110100001111011011000110001011111111101110110101101101001011110110010111101000111011001111"
c2 = "1011110110100110000001101000010111001000110010000110110001101001111101010000101000110100111010000010011001100100111001101010001001010001000011011001010100001100111011010011111100100101000001001001011001110010010100101011111010001110010010101111110001100010100001110000110001111111001000100001001010100011100100001101010101111000100001111101111110111001000101111111101011001010000100100000001011001001010000101001110101110100001111100001011101100100011000110111110001000100010111110110111010010010011101011111111001011011001010010110100100011001010110110001001000100011011001110111010010010010110100110100000111100001111101111010011000100100110011111011001010101000100000011111010010110111001100011100001111100100110010010001111010111011110110001000111101010110101001110111001110111010011111111010100111000100111001011000111101111101100111011001111"

crib_word = "the"
crib_word_bit = text_to_bits(crib_word)

crib_brute(xor(c1, c2), crib_word_bit)
```

Those are my first 15 results:

```
0: eP
1: Not processable
2: Not processable
3: Not processable
4: Not processable
5: Sgi
6: :v}
7: Not processable
8: L
9: Not processable
10: Not processable
11: Not processable
12: Not processable
13: {d
14: Not processable
15: Not processable
```

Nothing looks like part of the English language.
Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assuming that the messages consist of Unicode text in the UTF-8 encoding (or something similar enough to be analyzed as such), which means you're implicitly assuming the messages to consist of 8-bit bytes.  But they're each 847 bits long.  847 is not divisibly by 8, so something's wrong.

If you try printing out the bitwise XOR of the ciphertexts (i.e. `xor(c1, c2)`) and [plot its index of coincidence](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/35355) at various intervals, you'll notice peaks at multiples of 7 bits:

```
  1  53.10% #####################################################
  2  53.15% #####################################################
  3  53.14% #####################################################
  4  53.32% #####################################################
  5  53.10% #####################################################
  6  53.09% #####################################################
  7  58.77% ###########################################################
  8  53.28% #####################################################
  9  52.98% #####################################################
 10  53.08% #####################################################
 11  53.01% #####################################################
 12  53.27% #####################################################
 13  52.73% #####################################################
 14  58.60% ###########################################################
 15  53.04% #####################################################
 16  53.22% #####################################################
 17  52.86% #####################################################
 18  53.02% #####################################################
 19  52.91% #####################################################
 20  53.46% #####################################################
 21  58.74% ###########################################################
 22  52.95% #####################################################
 23  52.58% #####################################################
 24  53.60% ######################################################
 25  53.34% #####################################################
 26  52.65% #####################################################
 27  52.78% #####################################################
 28  59.19% ###########################################################
 29  52.58% #####################################################
 30  52.72% #####################################################
```

This strongly suggests that your messages are actually encoded with 7 bits per character, not 8.

Comment: Hey Ilmari, thanks for your answer :)
I adjusted my functions to convert to and from 7 bit strings, and at least everything is processable now, thanks for the help :)
In the first 100 results, I still don't see anything, that looks like part of an English word. Is there anything else wrong with the logic?
Technically, if there would be a "the" in m1, I'd get the decrypted result for m2 at this spot (and the other way around) right?

Comment: Nvm, I just didn't look through all decrypted outcomes properly.
Works like charm with 7 bits, thanks!